# Thymeleaf string concatenation in javascript loop

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to create comma separated string from `Map` I passed to template from my controller.

```
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        /*[# th:each="p, iterStat : ${ports}"]*/
           /*[[${iterStat.last} ?${p.value}: ${p.value} + ',']]*/
        /*[/]*/
    /*]]>*/
```

I would like to get

```
3,
2,
4,
7
```

instead I get

```
"3,"
"2,"
"4,"
7
```

can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because these are strings.

You can format string to integers using below code.

```
th:text="${#numbers.formatInteger(num,5)}"
```

Here 5 is mininum Integer Digits.

Refer this : https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html